# Running cluster command from Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-explorer

I am using Azure pipelines to run a command on the ADX cluster using Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX.PublishToADX.PublishToADX@1,
Even after explicitly declaring an inline script, looks like the task is searching for a file path.

```
- task: Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX.PublishToADX.PublishToADX@1               
  displayName: 'Run command'
  inputs:
   script: '.show version'
```

After execution below is the output I am getting from Pipeline
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYQq.png)

I was expecting the inline script to run rather than looking for a file pattern

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you need to use inline script in PublishToADX task.

By default, it will use the filepath target and search for the `.csl` file in PublishToADX task.

To meet your requirement, you need to define the `targetType: 'inline'`.

Here is the YAML sample:

```
- task: PublishToADX@1
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '.show version'
    kustoUrls: 'https://[YourCluster].kusto.windows.net:443?DatabaseName=[YourDatabase]'
```